# Rundeck Groovy Notification Plugin using Key Storage?

Tags: groovy, plugins, rundeck, key-storage

I'm trying to create a Groovy Notification plugin for Rundeck that has one property called `webhook_url`, which is stored in Key Storage. When adding the plugin to a job's notification config, it should have you choose the entry in Key Storage and it'll substitute that key's value.  I can get the rendering option to allow you to choose a key, however it substitutes the path to the key rather than the value it holds. It does not like my `valueConversion` parm in Groovy. Is this because I'm doing it wrong, or because Groovy Notification plugins don't support STORAGE_PATH_AUTOMATIC_READ?

Below is my config:

```
configuration{
    webhook_url title:"Webhook URL", required: true, type:"String", description:"dummy", renderingOptions:[valueConversion:StringRenderingConstants.ValueConversion.STORAGE_PATH_AUTOMATIC_READ, selectionAccessor:StringRenderingConstants.SelectionAccessor.STORAGE_PATH]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Which rundeck version are you using?

Comment: Hi there - this is on `3.4.0-20210614`. I get the same issue on version `3.3.11-20210507`

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay, i did a basic example and always i obtain the key path name instead the value, that's you case right? https://pastebin.com/MfrvXWp8

Comment: @MegaDrive68k - thanks, yes that is my experience as well; it populates the value with the key path/name vs. the actual stored value. I will submit this as an issue in GH. Thank you for confirming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No supported right now, you can suggest it [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues). It's accesible on Java/Groovy compiled [plugins](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/01-plugin-development.html#java-plugin-development).

Comment: Submitted bug: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/7147